# UTF-8 Characters are Truncated in Vim

Tags: vim, utf-8

When I have some UTF-8 characters in my document, they are sometimes truncated.  This appears to be an issue specific to certan fonts.  When I am `Courier 10 Pitch` the issue exists:

[image]

*(Note the first ☻ is truncated.)*

But if I switch to `Nimbus Mono L` the issue no long exists:

[image]

Is there a way that I can get `Courier 10 Pitch` to render properly?  It is my preferred font.

Vim Version Info:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 24 2014 15:40:38)
Included patches: 1-560
Compiled by JAKE
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cscope          +folding         +menu            +netbeans_intg   -sniff           +virtualedit
+arabic          +cursorbind      -footer          +mksession       +path_extra      +startuptime     +visual
+autocmd         +cursorshape     +fork()          +modify_fname    -perl            +statusline      +visualextra
+balloon_eval    +dialog_con_gui  +gettext         +mouse           +persistent_undo -sun_workshop    +viminfo
+browse          +diff            -hangul_input    +mouseshape      +postscript      +syntax          +vreplace
++builtin_terms  +digraphs        +iconv           +mouse_dec       +printer         +tag_binary      +wildignore
+byte_offset     +dnd             +insert_expand   -mouse_gpm       +profile         +tag_old_static  +wildmenu
+cindent         -ebcdic          +jumplist        -mouse_jsbterm   -python          -tag_any_white   +windows
+clientserver    +emacs_tags      +keymap          +mouse_netterm   -python3         -tcl             +writebackup
+clipboard       +eval            +langmap         +mouse_sgr       +quickfix        +terminfo        +X11
+cmdline_compl   +ex_extra        +libcall         -mouse_sysmouse  +reltime         +termresponse    -xfontset
+cmdline_hist    +extra_search    +linebreak       +mouse_urxvt     +rightleft       +textobjects     +xim
+cmdline_info    +farsi           +lispindent      +mouse_xterm     -ruby            +title           +xsmp_interact
+comments        +file_in_path    +listcmds        +multi_byte      +scrollbind      +toolbar         +xterm_clipboard
+conceal         +find_in_path    +localmap        +multi_lang      +signs           +user_commands   -xterm_save
+cryptv          +float           -lua             -mzscheme        +smartindent     +vertsplit       -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr
/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/g
lib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SO
URCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -l
pangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2
.0   -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that this font doesn't include this glyph, and that they're from a different font (a non-monospaced font or a much larger font, it seems). A quick glance at the Vim source shows that it's not Vim doing this, so it looks like GTK or the X11 font system is making a strange decision here (other GTK applications, such as gnome-terminal, suffer from the same problem). Not sure how to fix this, but you may want to rephrase/retag your question in that direction to attract attention from Gtk/Fontconfig experts...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem elsewhere, like in viewing and printing PDFs when using Courier "10 pitch" specifically in my word processor.

Try switching to just "Courier", and if that does not work, try downloading a Courier True Type Font from wherever on the Internet, and using that. You should be able to find a variation that matches your preference.

I know you would think that any "Courier" font should work since it goes back to the days of the IBM Selectric, but I had a similar problem, and fixed it just by switching to regular "Courier", without the "10 Pitch"